# How to get fragment instance from Fragment Scenario

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-testing, androidx

In my test case i want to get the view of the fragment that I launched in fragment scenario like this:

`val scenario = launchFragment<MyFragment>()`

In `MyFragment` I've got a method `rootView` that returns the bindet view of the fragment. In my test I want to get the root view and save it in another field. This is what I've been tried

```
val rootView: ViewGroup? = null
val scenario = launchFragment<MyFragment>()
scenario.onFragment { fragment -> fragment.rootView {
     rootView = fragment.rootView
  }
```

How can I save the the view from the fragment scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A late answer, but in case anyone else needs it:

```
val root: View? = null
val scenario = launchFragment<MyFragment>()
scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
    root = fragment.view?.rootView
}
```